# CMake error for OpenCV Building in Windows

Tags: opencv, cmake

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xFTXSDw_9U

I used Python version 3.7

CMake most recent

OpenCV version 4.1.0

OpenCV_contrib 4.1.0

I built OpenCV by referring to the video on the link, but experienced the following error:

---

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:193 (message):
  IPPICV: Download failed: 22;"HTTP response code said error"

  For details please refer to the download log file:

  C:/opencv/build/CMakeDownloadLog.txt

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv.cmake:42 (ocv_download)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:243 (download_ippicv)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:773 (include)
```

---

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:193 (message):
  ADE: Download failed: 22;"HTTP response code said error"

  For details please refer to the download log file:

  C:/opencv/build/CMakeDownloadLog.txt

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/gapi/cmake/DownloadADE.cmake:10 (ocv_download)
  modules/gapi/cmake/init.cmake:16 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:312 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:375 (_add_modules_1)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

---

```
 For details please refer to the download log file:

  C:/opencv/build/CMakeDownloadLog.txt

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.cmake:20 (ocv_download)
  modules/videoio/cmake/detect_ffmpeg.cmake:14 (download_win_ffmpeg)
  modules/videoio/cmake/init.cmake:3 (include)
  modules/videoio/cmake/init.cmake:24 (add_backend)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:312 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:375 (_add_modules_1)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

---

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:193 (message):
  FFMPEG: Download failed: 22;"HTTP response code said error"

  For details please refer to the download log file:

  C:/opencv/build/CMakeDownloadLog.txt

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.cmake:20 (ocv_download)
  modules/videoio/cmake/detect_ffmpeg.cmake:14 (download_win_ffmpeg)
  modules/videoio/cmake/init.cmake:3 (include)
  modules/videoio/cmake/init.cmake:24 (add_backend)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:312 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:375 (_add_modules_1)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

---

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the logs some downloads are failing: `HTTP response code said error`

The setup tries to e.g. download `IPPICV` from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/${IPPICV_COMMIT}/ippicv/`, given the fact that at the time of writing this answer, GitHub is experiencing an outage, this issue might disappear as soon as GitHub is operational again (https://www.githubstatus.com/)